# Eagle ground plane polygon

Tags: ground, eaglecad, ground-plane

I have been struggling to get the ground plane to fill in Eagle. Basically I have a very simple schematic, it is just VCC, two LEDs and GND.

[image]

[image]

Now I went into Eagle, selected draw polygon and drew a polygon over it. I then renamed it to GND to match it as such. Then I click RatsNest and nothing happens.

In all the tutorials this actually filled the GND plane correctly. I don't know why mine does not! I get that I have to put the polygon on the top plane, but how?

Comment: I got it, I have to put the polygon in the top plane. But how!!??

Answer (score 2):

Your bottom ground plane doesn't fill because you have two SMD parts, so filling it would not create any connections! If you put it on the top layer (simply select the top layer from the drop down menu after clicking the polygon tool), all required connections can be created. In case you want to use the bottom layer as GND, you need to create vias.

Answer (score 1):

The ground plane you created is on the bottom layer (blue) while your SMD parts are on the top layer (red). If you're just playing around, try creating a polygon on the top layer. After selecting the polygon tool, you have a dropdown menu in the toolbar. As an alternative you could hit the middle mouse button and get a window for selecting the layer. (middle mouse button would switch layers when routing signals, but with polygons it gives you full choice.)